# What is the maximum allowed length of a line in /etc/apt/sources.list in Debian 8?

Tags: debian, apt

We modify the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change the url to point to a local artifactory instance for local builds. For the past few days, our build have been failing with the error: `Line 1 too long in source list /etc/apt/sources.list`. The token and url are NOT malformed - the length really seems to be the problem.

I experimented with the lengths and discovered that 1024 is the maximum length it seems to support. Is there documentation or code I can refer to confirm this?

Edit: Found some [source code](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/cdrom.cc#L498) that looks helpful. Though I still don't see an explicit limit.

Comment: Which version of Debian? It may well be that older versions used a character array of some fixed length and newer versions use [the C++ string](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/sourcelist.cc#L370) so that newer versions don't set a limit.

Comment: @muru. Thanks for the comment. Updated the Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [the source code for apt](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/debian/jessie/apt-pkg/sourcelist.cc#L337) from Debian jessie, using 1024-character array as a buffer:

```
// CNC:2003-12-10 - 300 is too short.
char Buffer[1024];
```

In newer versions, the C++ `std::string` is used instead, removing the limit.

Note the code indicates that the Deb822 multi-line format (based on RFC 822) is also accepted in this version (see [`man sources.list`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/sources.list.5.en.html) for details). You might want to use it if you have problems with line length.